# Using recursion to calculate Log in Python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def recursivelog(n, x, b):
    assert n >= 0
    assert x >= 1
    assert isinstance(b, int) 
    assert b >= 2
    float(x)  # this statement does not change x so is useless here
    if(x < b):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1+ recursivelog(n-1, x/b, b)
```

`n`  indicates the number of steps (or recursive calls)

`x` the number for which to compute the logarithm

`b` the base of the logarithm

While the result will round to the nearest positive integer like

```
>>> recursivelog(100, 3)
4
```

How to get a real number result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you can do is to use binary search here.
Something like the following should work:

```
def calculate_log(lo, hi, val, base, level=0):
    level += 1
    if level > 100:
        return (lo+hi)/2.0
    mid = (lo + hi)/2.0
    if pow(base, mid) == val:
        return mid
    if pow(base, mid) < val:
        return solve(mid, hi, val, base, level+1)
    return solve(lo, mid, val, base, level+1)
```

You can make some adjustments for betterment. If you're worried about the efficiency, you can use your algorithm till your function returns a value smaller than the base. You should probably use this to calculate log for values smaller than the base.

Comment: What is the original value of lo and hi?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind recursive algorithms is you let them recurse until they reach a base case. Truncating a recursive algorithm may lead to unexpected results and errors especially when there are pending computations.

The integer logarithm can (should) be computed without having to deal with floats. Consider the actual meaning of the logarithm: `log(x, base) == c` implies `base ** c == x`. In lay mans terms, **how many times does one multiply `base` by its self to get `x`** corollary to that, **how many times does one need to divide `x` by `base` in other to get `c`**.

In your question, you want the integer logarithm, so, we perform the integer division. Here's your question reformulated:
**how many times does one need to divide (integer division) `x` by `base` in other to get `c`**.

With this, the program follows readily:

```
def rec_ilogn(x, n):
    """return the integer logarithm of x to base n"""
    assert x > 0, "Real logarithms are only defined for x > 0"
    if x < n:
        return 0
    return 1 + rec_ilogn(x//n, n)
```

Now to test the code:

```
>>> from math, import log
>>> ilogn = lambda x, n: int(log(x)/log(n)) # integer log(x, base)
>>> print([ilogn(i, 10) for i in range(1, 1000)] == [rec_ilogn(i, 10) for i in range(1, 1000)])
True
```